# PHP and libphonenumber: convert a string to PhoneNumber object?

Tags: php, symfony, laravel, libphonenumber

So I'm passing a phone number string to my PHP back-end. I'm trying to use Google's libphonenumber to perform a validation of the passed phone number.

Here is the string: "+447400123456" ($val)

```
$phoneUtil = \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberUtil::getInstance();
$phoneNumber = new \libphonenumber\PhoneNumber().setNationalNumber($val);
error_log(json_encode($phoneNumber));
$internationalFormatPhoneNumber = $phoneUtil->format($phoneNumber, \libphonenumber\PhoneNumberFormat::INTERNATIONAL);
error_log(json_encode($internationalFormatPhoneNumber));
```

Unfortunately, I keep getting

"local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\setNationalNumber()'"

All I want to do is check if the passed string is a valid international phone number (including mobiles) before I store it in my database.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm struggling with the documentation and keep getting errors.

Comment: replace the dot `.`  with `->` as follow: `$phoneNumber = new \libphonenumber\PhoneNumber()->setNationalNumber($val);`

Comment: `.` is the concatenation operator, so you're calling a top-level FUNCTION called `setNationalNumber()`, not a method of whatever object `PhoneNumber` returns.

Comment: I've made this same mistake a thousand time. Sometimes you have a brain hick-up when your used to switching between two languages.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem... I had to put it on two separate lines `$phoneNumber = new \libphonenumber\PhoneNumber();
   $phoneNumber->setNationalNumber($val);` Thank you for your very observant help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a dot operator `.` instead of the correct object operator `->` so you just need to replace the `.setNationalNumber($val)` to `->setNationalNumber($val)`.